# Solving a system of equation with Sympy, python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy, equation, equation-solving

I want to solve a system of equations. But I want to be able to precise the value to "get", and as a function of "what".

To better understand, I take an exemple from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156709/solving-system-of-nonlinear-equations-with-python#_=_), wich I modfified:

```
import sympy as sp
x, y, z = sp.symbols('x, y, z')
rho, sigma, beta = sp.symbols('rho, sigma, beta')
f1 = sigma * (y - x)
f2 = x * (rho - z) - y
f3 = x * y - beta * z
print sp.solvers.solve((f1, f2, f3), (x, y, z))
```

in

```
import sympy as sp
x, y, z, w = sp.symbols('x, y, z, w')
rho, sigma, beta = sp.symbols('rho, sigma, beta')
f1 = sigma * (y - x)
f2 = x * (rho - z) - y
f3 = x * y - beta * w
f4 = z - w
print sp.solvers.solve((f1, f2, f3, f4), (x, y, z))
```

So, as you can see, I replace **z** by **w** in the last equation and I add a new to precise **z = w**. 
But, **sympy (on python 2.7) is unable to solve this new system of equation!!**

*So my question:* How to get the result for x, y, z as a function of rho, sigma, beta. And more generally, how do we precise the variable "response variable".

*I think that could be very helpfull because, often, you don't want to developp your system of equation before asking python to solve it.*

In the same way, if I take a more complex example:

```
import sympy as sp
x, y, z, w, u = sp.symbols('x, y, z, w, u')
rho, sigma, beta = sp.symbols('rho, sigma, beta')
f1 = sigma * (y - x)
f2 = x * (rho - u) - y
f3 = x * y - beta * w
f4 = z - w
f5 = w - u
print sp.solvers.solve((f1, f2, f3, f4, f5), (x, y, z))
```

The response I get is:

```
[]
```

But as you see I have z = w = u
Son I should get the same answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is giving following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\temp\equation1.py", line 37, in  f3 = x * y - beta * w  NameError: name 'w' is not defined

Hence we pull symbol 'w' from  sympy symbols as below
`x, y, z, w = sp.symbols('x, y, z, w')`

You also mentioned you are trying to add  `z = w` , so once we add that to your code, it works.

**Working Code:**

```
import sympy as sp
x, y, z, w = sp.symbols('x, y, z, w')
rho, sigma, beta = sp.symbols('rho, sigma, beta')
z = w
f1 = sigma * (y - x)
f2 = x * (rho - z) - y
f3 = x * y - beta * w
f4 = z - w
print sp.solvers.solve((f1, f2, f3, f4), (x, y, z, w))
```

**Output:**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
[(0, 0, 0), (-sqrt(beta*rho - beta), -sqrt(beta*(rho - 1)), rho - 1), (sqrt(beta*rho - beta), sqrt(beta*(rho - 1)), rho - 1)]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not respond to my question. To be more precise, I have 8 equations and I want to have the expression of 2 variable as a function of the other. 

If I take a more complex example:


import sympy as sp
x, y, z, w, u = sp.symbols('x, y, z, w, u')
rho, sigma, beta = sp.symbols('rho, sigma, beta')
f1 = sigma * (y - x)
f2 = x * (rho - u) - y
f3 = x * y - beta * w
f4 = z - w
f5 = w - u
print sp.solvers.solve((f1, f2, f3, f4, f5), (x, y, z,))

The response I get is: 
[]

But as you see I have z = w = u
Son I should get the same answer!

Comment: Where did you define `z = w = u`?, if I define it explicitly, I am getting same answer. Try this: `import sympy as sp
x, y, z, w, u = sp.symbols('x, y, z, w, u')
rho, sigma, beta = sp.symbols('rho, sigma, beta')
z = w = u 
f1 = sigma * (y - x)
f2 = x * (rho - u) - y
f3 = x * y - beta * w
f4 = z - w
f5 = w - u
print sp.solvers.solve((f1, f2, f3, f4, f5), (x, y, z)) `