# Solving a system of transcendental equations with python

Tags: python, scipy, numeric, equation-solving, transcendental-equation

Assuming I have the following four equations:

1. cos(x)/x = a
2. cos(y)/y = b
3. a + b = 1
4. c sinc(x) = d sinc(y)

for unknown variables `x, y, a` and `b`. Note that `cos(x)/x=a` has multiple solutions. Similar goes for variable `y`. I am only interested in `x` and `y` values, which are first positive roots (if that matters).

You can safely assume `a, b, c` and `d` are known real constants, all positive.

In Mathematica the code to solve this would look something like:

```
FindRoot[{Cos[x]/x == 0.2 a + 0.1, 
          Cos[y]/y == 0.2 b + 0.1, 
          a + b == 1.0, 
           1.03*Sinc[x] == Sinc[y]*1.02}, 
          {{x, .1}, {y, .1}, {a, .3}, {b, .1}}]
```

which as a result returns

```
{x -> 1.31636, y -> 1.29664, a -> 0.456034, b -> 0.543966}
```

While this was quite easy, I have no idea how to do anything like that in python. So if somebody could kinda guide me (or simply show me how) to solve this, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving system of nonlinear equations with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156709/solving-system-of-nonlinear-equations-with-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

def your_funcs(X):

    x, y, a, b = X

    f = [np.cos(x) / x - 0.2 * a - 0.1,
         np.cos(y) / y - 0.2 * b - 0.1,
         a + b - 1,
         1.03 * np.sinc(x) - 1.02 * np.sinc(y)]

    return f

sol2 = root(your_funcs, [0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1])
print(sol2.x)
```

that will print

```
[ 1.30301572  1.30987969  0.51530547  0.48469453]
```

Your functions have to be defined in a way that they evaluate to 0, e.g. `a + b - 1` instead of `a + b = 1`.

A quick check:

```
print(your_funcs(sol2.x))
```

gives

```
[-1.9356960478944529e-11, 1.8931356482454476e-11, 0.0, -4.1039033282785908e-11]
```

So, the solution should be ok (please note that `e-11` is basically 0).

Alternatively, you can also use [`fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html):

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

sol3 = fsolve(your_funcs, [0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1])
```

which gives you the same result:

```
[ 1.30301572  1.30987969  0.51530547  0.48469453]
```

You can pass additional arguments using the `args` argument:

```
def your_funcs(X, fac_a, fac_b):

    x, y, a, b = X

    f = [np.cos(x) / x - fac_a * a - 0.1,
         np.cos(y) / y - fac_b * b - 0.1,
         a + b - 1,
         1.03 * np.sinc(x) - 1.02 * np.sinc(y)]

    return f

sol2 = root(your_funcs, [0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1], args=(0.2, 0.2))
print(sol2.x)
```

which gives you the "old" output:

```
[ 1.30301572  1.30987969  0.51530547  0.48469453]
```

If you run

```
sol2 = root(your_funcs, [0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1], args=(0.4, 0.2))
print(sol2.x)
```

then you receive:

```
[ 1.26670224  1.27158794  0.34096159  0.65903841]
```